# React: Trigger actions from class

Tags: reactjs

We are rewriting our currentexpress/jade-frontend to reactjs. In our current frontend we have classes that triggers actions, for example display a bootstrap modal, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.showUserInfo', function(event) {
  $('#modal-userInfo').modal('show');
});
```

We put these classes on random elements (div/buttons/html) in the solution. The element that triggers the action are different, but, the action is the same.

Conceptually I have a hard time understanding how you would do this in React. I could create a Component, with the modal, and wrap elements with this (i.e. instead of putting the class I wrap with the new component). But would this not generate extra elements around the wrapped component? And would it not create the modal in several places around the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component that can be used to wrap other elements.

```
function ShowUserInfo(props) {
  return (
    <div onClick={actions.showModal}>
      {props.children};
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you are using Flux, then make sure you have a corresponding action creator that dispatches a show modal action.

```
const actions = {
  showModal() {
    dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_MODAL' });
  }
};
```

Then wrap other React components in this new component to give them this behaviour.

```
<ShowUserInfo>
  <ProfilePicture />
</ShowUserInfo>
<Username />
```

Comment: But would this not create an unnecessary div around the element I wrap? It probably will not matter in the end, but it would be nice if you could leave the wrapped element unchanged, like you do in my current solution?

Comment: Remember, that you can't add a `click` listener directly to a React component, because it doesn't directly represent an element in the DOM, so you'll either need to wrap your component, or pass a click callback through props and hope the child component attaches it to a DOM node.

Comment: Perfect. Tested it out today and it works like a charm!